# Обход капчи Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет, пишу бота который будет заказывать вещи с определенного сайта. Интересует как можно обойти капчу при работе с Selenium. Я пробовал подгружать профиль своего аккаунта google к webdriver, но либо я делаю что-то не так, либо этот способ не работает. Буду вам очень благодарен если подскажите как это можно сделать без машинного обучения.

Comment: заказывайте решение на сервисах по решению капчи, ну либо пробуйте вытаскивать изображений и обрабатывать, все зависит от сложности капчи

Comment: @danilshik Другими способами обойти не выйдет? В моем боте очень важна скорость и боюсь если я буду обрабатывать изображения на это уйдет очень много времени. Точно такие же боты каким-то образом обходят капчу, возможно они работают не через selenium, и мне были бы интересны альтернативные способы решения проблемы.

Comment: ну Selenium сам по себе очень тяжелый и медленный. Попробуйте выяснить запросы, чтобы не работать на Selenium.

Comment: Капча постоянно присутствует или по мере запросов появляется?

Comment: @danilshik Капча присутствует только в браузере который открывается Selenium-ом, если заходить через обычный браузер и делать заказ - капчи не будет.

Comment: ссылку на сайт для которого вы пишите бота

Comment: @danilshik https://www.supremenewyork.com

Comment: Вам именно заказывать нужно? или вы просто парсите информацию. Просто стандартный bs4 вполне справляется со страницами, но если только не заказывать, так как там какое-то шифрование идет в запросе параметром data

Comment: @danilshik мне именно нужно сделать заказ

Comment: когда вы работаете через Selenium там вроде можно как-то узнать, что браузер работает именно через программу, но как это скрыть я не знаю, поэтому вам и капча идет

Comment: Какой браузер используете? И используете ли вы блокировщик рекламы (типа uBlock Origin)?

Comment: @AtachiShadow Браузер - Chrome, блокировщика рекламы нет.

Comment: Попробуйте с блокировщиком, если подумать "в лоб" то отслеживание Селениума может или через дополнительный флаг в Юзер-Агенте браузера (но вроде бы такой фигни Хром не делает, но я могу ошибаться, я в селениуме Хромом не пользовался уже больше 3-х лет) или с помощью "отпечатка" по функциям JavaScript от которых и должен спасти блокировщик рекламы. Ну и заодно, если что, можно попробовать Firefox))))))))

Comment: @AtachiShadow А как я могу подключить блокировщик рекламы к FirefoxDriver?

Comment: сейчас напишу в ответ)

Answer (score 5):

Сразу оговорюсь о том, почему перестал использовать Хром (есть вероятность что я не разобрался, и сейчас ошибаюсь, но) - когда в 60-й бета версии Хрома выпустили безголовый режим (headless), запускать в нём расширения было невозможно. Может быть в современных версиях в headless режиме уже можно использовать расширения, но тогда именно поэтому я перешёл на Firefox.

Для Chrome (приведённые команды имеют годовую давность, возможно это и сейчас работает)):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('load-extension=path\\to\\extension')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

`path\\to\\extension` - адрес папки, в которой лежит файл расширения

Для Firefox:

Я использую отдельный профиль для тестов (отдельная папка, и ссылка в коде на эту папку):

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('UB')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

в папке `UB` находится папка `extensions`, в которой лежит файл расширения `uBlock0@raymondhill.net.xpi`. То есть, полный путь от места исполнения скрипта до файла расширения выглядит так - `UB/extensions/uBlock0@raymondhill.net.xpi`.
Такой подход позволяет запускать любое количество расширений. И как плюс самого Firefox, я могу их использовать и в headless режиме)))) Но, как я сейчас заметил, в таком варианте сами расширения не обновляются. Мой uBlock для тестов версии 1.17.4, когда в обычном Firefox уже 1.18.6. Я пока не разбирался в том, как это исправить, что-бы вам побыстрее написать, что-бы вы попробовали хотя-бы так))))

И есть ещё второй вариант который я сам пока не использовал, но возможно, что предлагаемый в нём метод как раз и поможет расширениям обновляться (сам метод описан в статье на [DataRebellion](https://datarebellion.com/blog/using-firefox-extensions-with-selenium-in-python/)):

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.install_addon('path\\to\\extension.xpi', temporary=True)
```

`temporary=True` - говорит о том, что расширение устанавливается только на текущий сеанс
Возможно при `temporary=False` команда `install_addon` будет устанавливать расширение в профиль на "постоянной основе". Я буду пробовать)))))

Comment: а какое это имеет отношение к вопросу?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 вам стоит прочитать комментарии к вопросу, что-бы понимать, почему здесь такой ответ

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, чтобы расширение не загружалось каждый раз при запуске программы? Просто когда я запускаю бота, сначала идет установка AdBlock и только потом все остальные действия

Comment: @Mal Mel не устанавливайте тогда расширение через `install_addon`, а просто укажите папку профиля как в первом варианте)) Так браузер запускается с уже установленным расширением, и это не тратит ни время ни действия)) А капча появляется с блокировщиком?

Comment: @AtachiShadow к сожалению да, появляется, думаю единственный вариант это найти способ как-то скрыть работу через Selenium, либо использовать что-то другое для работы с браузером, но что - не знаю.

Comment: @AtachiShadow я установил uBlock и капча действительно перестала появляться! Но вопрос, как мне сделать так, чтобы в расширении по умолчанию стояла блокировка js-скриптов? Мне приходится делать это руками каждый раз при заходе на страницу.

Comment: @Mal Mel если вам нужно блокировать абсолютно все скрипты, то почему бы просто не выключать JS-движок в браузере, и uBlock тогда и не понадобиться? Или вы хотите блокировать конкретные скрипты силами uBlock?

Comment: @AtachiShadow Если честно, мне вообще все равно, главное чтобы заказ прошел и если можно блокировать все скрипты, то как я могу это сделать?

Comment: @Mal Mel я возможно вас не правильно понял, вы запускаете браузер и uBlock ничего не блокирует, и вы его вручную настраиваете? Или какие js-скрипты вы блокируете вручную?

Comment: @AtachiShadow Совершенно верно, по-умолчанию uBlock не блокирует js-скрипты и приходится в настройках ставить соответствующую галочку.

Comment: @Mal Mel, а uBlock показывает количество заблокированных источников до ручной настройки у себя на иконке?

Comment: @Mal Mel, так, давай-те разбираться)))) Вы запускаете браузер с расширением, и когда переходите на сайт, то uBlock не блокирует вообще ничего, но иконка в интерфейсе у него красная (активная). Так?

Comment: @Atachishadow Насколько я понимаю он что-то все таки блокирует, но это точно не js-скрипты. Вообще если бы можно было каким-то образом заблокировать только скрипты отвечающие за google капчу - это было бы то что мне нужно.

Comment: @Mal Mel так он и должен заблокировать "google-analytics.com" и "googletagservices.com", я просто не понимаю, про какие скрипты вы говорите, те что он находит, или какие-то дополнительные, которые вам не нужны. Если вам нужны какие-то дополнительные правила, то uBlock можно настраивать внешним конфиг-файлом, но тут я вам не помогу. И ещё, капча гугловская блокируется когда uBlock в стандартной конфигурации, или только после того, как вы его настроите? И какие настройки вы используете?

Comment: @AtachiShadow мой бот должен автоматически покупать вещи на определенном сайте, об этом я писал выше, и мне кажется, что помимо всего прочего он блокирует скрипты отвечающие за оплату вещи, потому что сама оплата не проходит, появляется ошибка.

Comment: @Mal Mel вы можете посмотреть в списке заблокированных источников в самом uBlock, нажмите левой кнопкой, и в левой части всплывающего окошка будут показаны все источники, попробуйте настроить их так, что-бы скрипты оплаты не блокировались, потом добавите их в настройки uBlock, что-бы он всегда так работал