# Хочу спарсить с OLX.ua номера телефонов, но ничего не выходит, выбивает надпись «зафиксирована подозрительная активность», что можно сделать?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Хочу спарсить с OLX.ua номера телефонов, но ничего не выходит, выбивает надпись "зафиксирована подозрительная активность", использую прокси, перепробовал огромный список имеющихся у меня проксей, страница загружается, как только начинает переходить по ссылкам появляется данное окно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можно сделать, чтобы решить данную проблему?
Код:
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random

urls = open("input.txt", "r")
for url in urls:

```
myProxy = random.choice(open('proxy.txt').readlines())
print(myProxy + "\n")

def get_url(driver): 
    driver.get(url)
    print("GOT URL")
    time.sleep(3)


def press_cookie_btn(driver):
    cookie_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='topinfo rel']"
                                              "/button[@class='cookie-close abs cookiesBarClose']")
    cookie_btn.click()
    print("COOKIE")
    time.sleep(2)


def page_pagination(driver):
    ars = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink']")
    urls_1 = []
    for ar in ars:
        url_1 = ar.get_attribute("href")
        urls_1.append(url_1)
        print(url_1)
    for url_2 in urls_1:
        driver.get(url_2)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)



def main():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % myProxy)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    get_url(driver)
    press_cookie_btn(driver)
    page_pagination(driver)
    driver.quit()


main()
```

urls.close()
    введите сюда код
    введите сюда код

Comment: Используется расширение типа блокировщика ublock? Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962268/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B8-selenium) и комменты к нему

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'uBlock0@raymondhill.net.xpi' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home. Появляется данная ошибка, что можно сделать?

Comment: А если исправлять, то оно просто не видит данный файл

Comment: Что внутри `options.add_argument(...)`? Абсолютный путь?

Comment: Да, я указываю абсолютный путь и оно выбивает то что не найдено, хотя файл там явно есть

Comment: @Total Pusher, возможно ли указать uBock’у что надо блокировать, а что нет? Просто он банит абсолютно все скрипты, из-за этого не удаётся получить номера телефонов?

Comment: Я не использовал uBock. Просто видел тут на ruSO такой способ обхода. Ссылку я дал в первом комменте. Было еще более детальное обсуждение использования блокировщиков для обхода какой-то каптчи, но не смог найти этот вопрос.

Comment: Вы столкнулись сейчас с новой проблемой. Напишите свой новый вопрос, со ссылкой на этот, где в виде примечания напишите, почему собственно нужен этот блокировщик - чтобы не столнуться с "проблемой молотка". Это лучший способ решить эту новую проблему.