# Почему банят с прокси?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

Пытаюсь с помощью selenium поменять ip адрес с помощью proxy и каждый раз очищать куки.
Захожу на сайт https://icanhazip.com, действительно показывает новый ip.
Но как только зайду на страницу яндекса, вылетает капча.
Аналогичная ситуация и с гуглом. 
Как убрать капчу из гугла и яндекса? В инете нет статей на эту тему, не возникают подобные баны

```
from selenium import webdriver

sp = ['https://icanhazip.com', 'https://yandex.ru/search/?text=пирожное']

# https://icanhazip.com покажет тот адрес, который в переменной proxy
# но яндекс почему-то негативно реагирует на поведение скрипта

proxy = '51.158.180.179:8811'

caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['marionette'] = True

caps['proxy'] = {
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "httpProxy": proxy,
    "ftpProxy": proxy,
    "sslProxy": proxy
}

for url in sp:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.get(url)
    print(driver.get_cookies())
```

Comment: прокси может быть не рабочий, забаненный

Comment: Например, потому что не Вы один используете этот прокси, и поведение других пользователей заставило Гугл относиться к этому IP с подозрением.

Comment: тут на SO [советовали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962357/287469) ставить расширение типа блокировщика рекламы, он решает проблему. Или не решает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Яндекс использует много параметров, начиная от куков заканчивая ID и фингерпринтами.
Если запросов не много = используй сервис антикапчи.