# Какие данные о системе может передать браузер?

Tags: python, selenium, браузер, webbrowser

Какие данные о системе может передать браузер на данный момент 04.2021? Кроме данных входящих в юзерагент (ОС, её разрядность и сами данные о браузере) и fingerprint (расширения, размер окна, часовой пояс и тд)

Может ли он передать все данные о процессоре/видеокарте/материнской плате/любой другой периферии или может точные данные об операционной системе (напр, имя компьютера/пользователя), чтобы идентифицировать пользователя? И если все эти данные предаются, то можно ли их благодаря python/selenium их подменить?

p.s. Использую python selenium для скрапинга (со сменой ip/useragent'a/рандомной генерацией fingerprint'a) и хочется максимальной анонимности

Comment: Зайдите на сайт [browserleaks.com](https://browserleaks.com/) и узнайте что передается и каким способом это делается. Часть - косвенные методы, например что-то рендерится через canvas, и смотрятся результаты. А блокировать эти данные можно, для чего в FireFox есть расширения типа блокировщиков. Вам для обхода бана/каптчи нужно? Вот есть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962357/287469)

Comment: PS. Если хотите посмотреть, что именно передается при заходе на сайт, это делается в консоли браузера, вкладка сеть. Также можно поставить MITM прокси, например он уже есть с поддержкой HTTPS в KaliLinux